# jsPDF - pagesplit for multiple pdf pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, jspdf, html2pdf

I am trying to generate a PDF document via jsPDF which has enough content to fill out 2-3 A4 pages. The problem here is that jsPDF cuts off the content after the first page, not generating any of the further pages.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var options = {
         pagesplit: true
    };
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    $('#SavePDFbutton').click(function () {                     
        doc.fromHTML($('#timeline').html(), 15, 15, {
            'width': 170,
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
        });

        doc.save('<?php echo $_SESSION['Holidex']; ?>-DM-Logbook.pdf');
    });
</script>
```

I have been playing around the the `pagesplit` option, but without success. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
doc.fromHTML($('#timeline').html(), 15, 15, {
  'width': 170,
  'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers,
  'pagesplit':true
});
```

can you try with the parameters above?

Comment: only results in one empty, white page. Seems like no text is picked up.